# What version of ADT is bundle with Android SDK?

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, version

What is version of Eclipse that is bundle with Android SDK? 3.8 or 4.2 ?

Comment: Did you download it to find out for yourself?

Comment: My latest Android SDK uses Eclipse 4.2 and ADT 21.x

Answer (score 0):

None, because the ADT plugin can be downloaded trough an HTTP URL in the Eclipse package manager.

EDIT

If you want to know the latest version that is available online simply read the content of

https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/site.xml

If you want to know the version number of a given ADT plugin, which is nothing more than a jar file, open it with an archive application and read the content of the `feature.xml` file.

Comment: Ok, I know but i don't want to download it. I just want to know. :)

Comment: @ext well, as you may already know there is no schedule for that, a new ADT is published just when it's ready, you can take a sneak peek at the xml file inspected by Eclipse itself to know the actual ADT release number https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/site.xml

Comment: This is not strictly true, as Google is distributing the "ADT Bundle" that includes a copy of Eclipse. That being said, I am not sure what version of Eclipse is in that bundle.

Comment: @CommonsWare in the OP's question there is not even a reference to a specific release of the android SDK ;) If you just have the "jar file" open it with an archive manager and inspect the "feature.xml" file.

Comment: I mention lastest version of Android SDK.